# laravel 9 executting php phpstan

Tags: laravel, phpstan

I'm running
`php ./vendor/bin/phpstan analyse --error-format github`

I get this issues:

```
::error file=app/Models/User.php,line=55,col=0::Method App\Models\User::roles() return type with generic class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany does not specify its types: TRelatedModel
::error file=app/Models/User.php,line=66,col=0::Method App\Models\User::authorizeRoles() has parameter $roles with no value type specified in iterable type array.
::error file=app/Models/User.php,line=80,col=0::Method App\Models\User::hasAnyRole() has parameter $roles with no value type specified in iterable type array.
```

this's user.php model

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Type\Integer;

class User extends Authenticatable {
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'image',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param array $roles
     * @return boolean
     */

    public function authorizeRoles(array $roles)
    {
        if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
        abort(401, 'Esta acción no está autorizada.');
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string|array $roles
     * @return boolean
     */

    public function hasAnyRole(string|array $roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $role
     * @return boolean
     */

    public function hasRole(string $role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @return boolean
     */

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', 'Administrador')->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

what's wrong??

PHPStan focuses on finding errors in your code without actually running it. It catches whole classes of bugs even before you write tests for the code. It moves PHP closer to compiled languages in the sense that the correctness of each line of the code can be checked before you run the actual line.

Comment: `belongsToMany` doesn't return an `array` ... relationship methods return Relationship Type objects

Comment: It fixed, I update the question

Comment: `@return array` above your `public function roles()` is wrong; your code says `return $this->belongsToMany()->withTimestamps()`; that is **not** an Array. Read your output; it's telling your exactly that. Is there something unclear about that?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L475    that is what it returns

Comment: I fixed that issue, added type object..... but I'm having others error

Answer (score 0):

1. This error happens because `BelongsToMany` is a generic class in Larastan. And you need to provide the generic types. So change your docblock to `BelongsToMany<Role>` Or you can disable this check with `checkGenericClassInNonGenericObjectType: false` More information here: https://phpstan.org/config-reference#vague-typehints
2. The remaining errors are because PHPStan wants you to specify types for `array` type. There is a blog post with more information about it here: https://phpstan.org/blog/solving-phpstan-no-value-type-specified-in-iterable-type Basically you need to do `string[]` or `array<int, string>` or something similar.